# Solving for Amps in a selfmade furnace/heating resistance

Tags: power-supply, current, transformer, thermal, power-consumption

I made a heating resistance out of a graphite bar I found. I will adapt this bar to a furnace in order be able to sinter Si3N4 (1850°C). 
After measuring dimensions, max. load of Si3N4 in the furnace and adding heat loss (radiation, conduction and convection). I calculated I will need Q=mcΔt2-t1= 1.1664e+7 Joules or 3.24 kWh to achieve the 1850°C for sinterization.

I also already calculated the Amps the graphite bar will draw with 220V AC single phase and the measured Ohms with a multimeter.

Now, I need to know two things:

1.if my graphite bar is strong enough and can supply the 3.24kWh the Si3N4 needs?

I pretend to discover this by finding out the amount of Amps required in oder to supply the 3.24kWh with 220V AC single phase and compare it with the Amps I already know my graphite bar draws when conected to the 220V.

If the required Amps are more than the ones my graphite bar draws, then I think the bar wont be strong enough.
I want to use the P=VI formula but time is in the way (the hours in the kW). Maybe is something stupid but, can I still use the P=VI formula? or how can I find out the Amps in this case?

2.What transformer can I use to supply that amount of energy?

If I can find out the Amps in the first question, then I think this 2nd. question is already solved as well. I will already have the Amps and the Volts, so I will find something to lower the volts and rise the amps to ease the supply. I hope I am correct?

Thanks for your help, I edited my post and added more information, hoppefully it meets your standards now...

Comment: Why do you think your graphite bar will withstand this power?

Comment: You've quoted a total energy for sintering, but not power, or time which would allow the power to be calculated. Do you have a perfectly adiabatic kiln, where the time doesn't matter? If you want to know amps, then you need the power, and the bar resistance.

Comment: The gross sloppiness with units makes it unclear what your situation really is.  You are mixing up power and energy, and can't even get the abbreviation for "kilo" right, although maybe you actually think Kelvin-Watt-hours is somehow relevant here.  You apparently have no concept of resistance, then ask about something else (a transformer) it seems you know little about.  It's OK to ask about fundamentals, but not to wildly throw around fundamentals incorrectly while asking about something higher level.  Closing this disaster.

Comment: I´m sorry for my mistakes and lack of clarity, it is the first time I ask something in this blog. Clearly (like everyone) I will get better with practice.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in development and will be edited as you supply more details.

> I made a heating resistance out of a graphite bar I found. The thermal energy I need to sinter the material I want is 3.24 KWh (converted from joules).

First, mind your units. 'K' is kelvin but it is obvious in this instance that you mean kWh.

Next, assuming that your energy calculation is correct there is a problem. 3.24 kWh could be obtained by providing 3.24 kW for one hour or 32.4 kW for 6 minutes or 0.00324 W for 1000 hours (about six weeks). Clearly the last option wouldn't 
get the bar hot enough to sinter anything.

> Now I need to know how [many] amps the graphite resistance going to draw from the 220 V single phase AC supply in order to give the 3.24 kWh the material I want to sinter needs.

You are approaching this the wrong way.

- More than likely you need to work out the current density required to heat the bar enough to sinter your material. This will be in A/mm² (or similar).
- Then find the dimensions of your bar. This will be mm².
- Then calculate the current required: \$ I = \frac {A/{mm}^2}{{mm}^2} \$.
- Now you need to work out the resistance, \$ R \$, of your bar and work out if it is going to be constant during sintering or will it change.
- At this point you can calculate the voltage required from \$ V = IR \$.

> This so I can find out the transformer I need to conect to the heating resistance.

You then need a transformer with an output voltage of \$ V \$ and a current rating > \$ I \$.

---

Update after question updated

> If the required amps are more than the ones my graphite bar draws, then I think the bar wont be strong enough.

In electrical terms you are saying, "If the resistance of the bar is too high then not enough current will flow, the A/mm² will be too low and the bar will not get hot enough." This is correct. In this case you could make the resistance lower by decreasing the length of the bar.

[Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/rstiv.html) lists the resistivity, ρ, of graphite at 3 to 60 x 10\$^5\$ Ωm depending on impurities. I think you will have to go with your measured values but you need to be careful in case the resistivity drops dramatically as it heats up. (The current might rise beyond what your power supply can handle.)

Comment: I dont want to sinter the graphite bar, I want to sinter another material in a furnace with the graphite bar as a resistance. I already calculated the V,I,R for the graphite bar. But it wont help me if the bar can´t emit the thermal energy the material I want to sinter needs (Q=mcΔt2-t1). The energy is calculated in Joules and I can only convert them to kWh or Wh. So, how can I know the amps required (with kWh and 200v AC) in other to discover if my resistance is fit for the task? Will it draw the required amps?

Comment: I corrected my misunderstanding already. Add your measurements and calculations in the original post. Since your V and R both seem to be fixed you can now work out current from \$ I = \frac {V}{R} \$ and power from \$ P = VI \$. Whether that much power is enough to sinter your material depends on how much heat is conducted away and lost to the surroundings. If it is enough power then \$ seconds = \frac {energy\;(J)}{power\;(W)} \$. Edit your original question.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will add measurements and calculations in the original post.

Comment: Can you add a link to an article or video on your technique? I'm not in the least familiar with it.

Comment: I´m still in the theory phase and cannot supply the energy to the bar in an open atmosphere because the graphite bar will oxidize as soon as it hits the 500°C. I will build a nitrogen chamber for the furnance and then run the first test to get the 1850°C. I already edited my question and added more information. I can share a video of the tests as soon as I build the chamber, but I rather calculate the most I can in order to prevent a trail and error experiment because the temperature I want to get is very high and dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

> After measuring dimensions, max. load of Si3N4 in the furnace and adding heat loss (radiation, conduction and convection). I calculated I will need Q=mcΔt2-t1= 1.1664e+7 Joules or 3.24 kWh to achieve the 1850°C for sinterization.

You need to know the power, not the energy. "mcΔt2-t1" (I presume c is the specific heat capacity of the Si3N4 you want to heat) gives you the amount of energy to heat it, but this doesn't take the losses into 
account.

Losses are proportional to the temperature delta between the inside and the outside of your insulated furnace, multiplied by the thermal conductivity of your insulator and its area. So, you need to calculate the thermal loss power at maximum temperature. I presume you already know about this.

I'm not familiar with high temperature materials, but the principle is the same as with low temperature stuff... Let's consider a box of one cubic meter. The area of its walls is \$S=6 m^2\$. The temperature inside is \$\Delta T=50°C\$ hotter than outside. It is insulated with \$e=20mm\$ thick polystyrene, which has a thermal conductivity of \$ \lambda = 0.04 \frac{W}{m.K}\$...

Thus the power flowing through the insulator is :

\$ P = \frac{\lambda S}{e} \Delta T = 600W \$

This means if we don't put a 600W heater inside, the inner temperature will drop. And if we want to raise the inner temperature, we need to heat with more than 600W. So after doing the same calculation with your furnace and its insulator, you'll know the **Minimum power** you need. Of course you'll need a lot more, since you also have to heat the material inside, and do it fast enough, since losses through insulation increases with time.

Now you also have a maximum power. You need to know how the heat will be transferred from the graphite heating element to the Si3N4 (by convection in gas, radiation, etc?). Too much heating power would fry the graphite if the heat isn't transferred fast enough to the Si3N4. Perhaps too much power would damage the Si3N4 instead of doing the sintering you want... Maybe you'd like several graphite rods to heat the stuff more evenly, not have any cold spots... I don't know, that's the hard part ;) but this will give you an idea of the maximum power you can use.

Once you know this, you choose the power you'll actually use, with a simple algorithm: "not enough power and it heats too slow and uses more energy than it should in the end, too much power and the product is fried."

So, how much Watts do you actually need?

Now, can your graphite rod provide that power? Most likely it can, if it's big enough, it's just a resistor after all, all you need is to adjust the voltage.

So, calculate the ohms value of your graphite bar. Or measure it. Allow a margin for error, as the resistivity of the stuff depends on temperature.

[image]

Then since P=V^2/R then you have your voltage.

If you find that a voltage like 20-80% of your mains RMS voltage works, then you're in luck: just connect the thing to the mains, using a suitable triac dimmer to adjust power.

If it needs something like 10-40V and you're in 230V land, then you'll need a transformer, or other kind of power supply, to be chosen knowing the current you'll actually need... and you don't know yet about that.

If it needs more than your mains voltage, then you'll need a transformer to boost the voltage (but we can't know that yet).